# Extracting data from HTML page using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, html-parsing

I'm trying to get my level of each skill from
https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=Feed%20Meh%20Dog

It's a table but I don't see a table id anywhere. I just need to know what id or class I should be using.

Tried multiple tutorials, but all have a straight forward table class or id.
There is a div ID which I think I should use, just not sure how to extract each specific row/skill.

final Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=Feed%20Meh%20Dog").get();

```
    for (Element row : document.select("WHAT DO I PUT HERE tr")); {
        final String Attack = row.select("WHAT DO I PUT HERE")
        final String Defence = row.select("WHAT DO I PUT HERE")
        final String Strength = row.select("WHAT DO I PUT HERE")
    }
```

Just want to output the row, or individual skills to the console. Any help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: It's very likely filled in by JavaScript after the page load.

Comment: @chrylis So how would I find the class or IDs?

Comment: May I ask why you're trying to use this method to extract the data instead of using the official API? 

In your case [https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Feed%20Meh%20Dog](https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Feed%20Meh%20Dog)

Comment: @JoshuaHunt isn't Jsoup supposed to make it easier?

Comment: @NickRags That depends on what you mean by easier. With the API all you need to do is parse the JSON... and a little more since their API is quite frankly garbage. The order of skills is the same on the website starting with Overall. I have also noted a pattern, although the Rank,Level,Xp is comma delimited, the skills themselves are space delimited, followed by the minigame stats at the end. If you can't figure out a way using Jsoup (which seems just as tedious looking at the HTML) I would happily write a little wrapper for that API endpoint you could use?

Comment: @JoshuaHunt That would be awesome. Where do you see the data being space or comma delimited, the HTML?

Comment: @NickRags I looked at the raw api data, I've tried to illustrate what I mean [here](https://i.imgur.com/i3IJtYQ.png). I'll get on that wrapper in a short while, I'll comment back here when It's ready with a Github link. I assume you're familiar with either maven/gradle? EDIT: I've just realised the API isn't even JSON it's just a string, so you could Jsoup that link and do whatever with that... I'll still make the wrapper though.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt I'm not familar with those actually. And what do you mean by the Api is a string. Sorry for the questions, I just want to learn as much as possible.

Comment: @NickRags I mean that I assumed the structure of the data would be in JSON form (you can learn about Json and what it looks like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp)) but instead its just a long string that's sparingly formatted. What IDE are you using for this project? My go-to for the past few years is IntelliJ for various reasons. I would recommend learning about maven/gradle, which do the same job so I'd start with gradle, you can learn more about that [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/what_is_gradle.html).

Comment: @JoshuaHunt I'm using intellij now.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt So what's the easiest way to do this. JSoup looks pretty easy, I just don't know which html parameters I need.

Comment: @NickRags If you want to use Jsoup, I would use it against the API link I provided above and since the data is all in the body with no other tags, just grab the body as a String and then format it the way you like it. However if you learn how to use gradle, (in it's most basic form at least) the wrapper I'm writing now will be much easier. I'd still recommend doing the first method though as a learning exercise!

Comment: @JoshuaHunt Also thanks for everything, means a lot

Comment: @JoshuaHunt ohhhhhhh, okay I see now. Just grab the data as a string and format it. Still not sure how to do that haha

Comment: Yeah, using the link I posted before [https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Feed%20Meh%20Dog](https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Feed%20Meh%20Dog) you would do `String foo = document.select(body);` and then it's a case of splitting the string into its various bits`String[] skills = foo.split(" ");` would split the skills up, then `String[] stats1 = skills[x].split(",");` would split the skills up into their parts.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt So for body, I need to put HTML code, right?

Comment: @NickRags I'll write an example of what you are looking for as the answer.

Comment: @JoshuaHunt Thank you so much, is there anyway I can add you on discord or something?

Comment: @JoshuaHunt Didn't work

Comment: @NickRags I've just realised that my answer is missing characters... (which is why it probably didn't work) as in they're present in the editor but I mustn't have escaped them properly. Add me and we'll discuss it further there, it'll be quicker than waiting for responses :P

Comment: @JoshuaHunt no your discord didn't work lol. What is it again?

Comment: @NickRags oh, my bad! 0x00000008#0001 (not been up long)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the official API if you want to get the data you're looking for easily. Using this link: `https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=` To do that with Jsoup in a hacky kind of way would look a little like this...

```
    final Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Feed%20Meh%20Dog").get();
    final Element body = document.selectFirst("body");

    String[] rawSkills = body.html().split(" ");
    ArrayList<String[]> skills = new ArrayList<>();

    for(String s: rawSkills ) {
        skills.add(s.split(","));
    }

    System.out.println(skills.get(0)[1]);
```

Then to select an individual skill, you would do something like `skills.get(x)[y]` with x being the index in the array the skill is (starting 0) and y being which piece of information from the skill you want. 0 being rank, 1 being skill level and 2 being xp.

The API doesn't provide names of each skill so you would have to do that manually. The skill order is as it is on the high scores page [here](https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/hiscorepersonal.ws?user1=Feed%20Meh%20Dog).

EDIT: I've taken the liberty to create a small Java wrapper for this specific endpoint which you can find [here](https://github.com/BasketBandit/RuneAPI.java).